# MYSQL - Delete a record within its row index

Tags: mysql

I'm a little bit confused about deleting a record based on its row index or count.Suppose I have these three rows:

```
ID | userId | postID  
15      1       10  
16      1       10  
17      1       10
```

These data are fetched using the query:

```
SELECT * FROM postimages where postID=10
```

I want to remove one of this records based on an index which is in a variable called `index` .. the index could be 1,2 or 3 so maybe the query should be like:

```
delete from postimages where postID=10  -- here I'm stuck
```

Is it possible or not?

Comment: why not ? for eg: `delete from postimages where postID=10 and ID = 16` will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible, just use `limit-offset`, like this:

```
delete from postimages where postID=10 limit 1 offset 1
```

this query will delete 1 row because `limit 1`,
and this row will be 2nd because `offset 1`.

To delete 1st row - use `limit 1 offset 0`,

to delete 2nd row - use `limit 1 offset 1`,

to delete 3d row - use `limit 1 offset 2` and so on.

**Disclaimer**: With purpose to have reliable experience you must specify `order by` clause, like:

```
delete from postimages where postID=10 order by ID limit 1 offset 1
```

Comment: now the offset value is the value inserted into my index variable so replacing 1 by index variable I'll get what I've been seeking

Comment: But the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` are meaningless without an `ORDER BY`, no?

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY is essentially meaningless

Comment: @Zack Yes, it's better to use `order by` clause, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes, you're right, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @VladimirKovpak Thanks a lot

Comment: @RaizadaDev Happy to help!)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `n`-th record like this. Make sure you order the result by the column you want, in this case the `id` column:

```
DELETE FROM postimages WHERE postID=10 ORDER BY id LIMIT n-1,1
```